# Client side Socket responses handling like authorization and error cases

Tags: java, android, sockets, socket.io

I've been trying to implement [Socket.io-client-java](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java) to my project.

However I have several questions:

If the user is not authorized I can disconnect the `socket` connection from the server side. In this case I can handle the situation on the client socket `onDisconnect` event.

If the user is not authorized I can return an error like `Not authorized`. Then I can handle the situation on the client socket `onError` event.

**question:** Which one is the right approach?

If I make an API request, I'll check the `HTTP status code` of the response to realize that I have to get a new `Access Token` and have to send the same request again.

**question:** How do I know if I need to get a new Access Token when using `socket`?

Also I can know that a server internal error has been occurred by checking `HTTP status code`. Then I can even check error code and message from the response body.

**question:** How do I manage errors when using `socket`?

I got a bit confused.

***Both partial answer or a complete answer would be great !***

ps: Sorry if my questions have mistakes about socket logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing my solutions:

**question:** Which one is the right approach?
**answer:** Both of them!

So, if a socket connection is not authorized I use the steps below on the server side:

1. I return an error through [`socket.io` middleware](http://socket.io/docs/migrating-from-0-9/#authentication-differences) by using the following code: 
   `next(new Error("ERR_TOKEN"))`
2. Disconnect the client socket by considering system resources and security by using the following code: 
   `setTimeout(function(){socket.disconnect()}, 200)`

**question:** How do I know if I need to get a new Access Token when using socket?
**answer:** Checking the error message on the client side.

I created several constant error code that are used both server and client sides. (`ERR_NO_AUTH_HEADER`, `ERR_AUTH_HEADER_VALUE`, `ERR_TOKEN`)

At the client side's `onError` event:

1. I disconnect the socket by using the code of `socket.disconnect();`. Otherwise I cannot send a new request with the new access token. Actually server will disconnect the connection. Nevertheless I disconnect at the client side too to ensure.
2. I check the error code. If the code is `ERR_TOKEN` I get a new token from AccountManager in Android. AccountManager gets new `authtoken` and stores it to its own cache for future use.

**question:** How do I manage errors when using socket? 
**answer:** I solve that just like previous answer.

Hope this helps to others...